# Create the MongoDB Windows Service command does nothing

Tags: windows, mongodb, batch-file, windows-services, windows-server-2016

When I tried to create the MongoDB Windows service following the comments given in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#create-the-mongodb-service) it does nothing except return the help explanation of the windows command and exits.

This is the command (same as given in the documentation):

```
sc.exe create MongoDB binPath= "\"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin\mongod.exe\" ^
  --service --config=\"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\mongod.cfg\""DisplayName= "MongoDB" start= "auto"
```

Surprisingly this has always worked on my PC running Windows 10 but not on this server. I'm running this over an AWS server running Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 64 bit OS. MongoDB v3.6.3.

How can I run this command so that I can set this up as a windows service?

[image: create the MongoDB Windows Service command does nothing]

Comment: could you post the full command in the question? maybe you need a white space before DisplayName=

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Your two lines are supposed to be one, the caret, **`^`**, is supposed to escape the line return. Your string has unbalanced doublequotes  because you're incorrectly trying to escape the line return in the middle of a doublequoted string.

Comment: Can you suggest the corrected command please? Also you may please verify/check the documentation that I've given above. Surprisingly this has always worked on my PC Win 10 but not on this server

Comment: I could; can you show me exactly where in the [your link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#create-the-mongodb-service), the command you've shown is the `"same as given"`?

Comment: You have no space between the closing quote and `DisplayName`.

Comment: @Compo see https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#create-the-mongodb-service

Comment: Thanks for providing the correct link, yes they have it wrong too! Did you try the escaped split line version in my answer?

Comment: I had tried simply without the caret and it didnt work, but let me try your suggestion with space before the `DisplayName`

Comment: @CodeCaster, Thanks for sharing the correct link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to either remove the caret, **`^`** and use a single line:

```bat
sc.exe create MongoDB binPath= "\"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin\mongod.exe\" --service --config=\"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\mongod.cfg\"" DisplayName= "MongoDB" start= "auto"
```

Or to close the doublequotes before the caret, **`^`** and reopen them on the next line:

```bat
sc.exe create MongoDB binPath= "\"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin\mongod.exe\" --service "^
 "--config=\"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\mongod.cfg\"" DisplayName= "MongoDB" start= "auto"
```

Comment: and @CodeCaster Thank you both. I've edited the answer above to mention "add space before `DisplayName` "